# Segmentation fault with getline in C++

Tags: c++, string, getline, fault

I'm working on an assignment for my programming class. One of the given function prototypes is:

```
string read_text(const string & prompt);
```

I wrote the function definition as:

```
string read_text(const string & prompt)
{
    cout << "Enter your text: ";
    getline(cin, prompt);
}
```

However, this gives me an error:

```
freq.cpp: In function 'std::string read_text(const std::string&)':
freq.cpp:80: error: no matching function for call to 'getline(std::istream&, const std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&)'
```

I read that getline is not supposed to refer to a `const` variable, so I removed that part, but now I get a Segmentation fault when I run the program.

Comment: What code are you using when a segmentation fault occurs? (P.S - GDB is your friend)

Comment: Show us how you call it and what you do with the string after you pass it.

Comment: you're passing in the const prompt to getline, you're supposed to pass in the string variable you want the read text written into.

Comment: There's no seg-fault, but complation errors apparently.

Comment: This post helped me even though its rating was negative, so I upped it. I had a totally specialized function template in which I forgot to include a return statement. It actually did cause a segmentation fault, unlike OP's program

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a return value. Make it:

```
string read_text()
{
    string prompt
    cout << "Enter your text: ";
    getline(cin, prompt);
    return prompt;
}
```

Disclaimer: No error checks

Answer (score 2):

It seems you are confusing a compile-time error with a segmentation fault: these are two rather different things. Compile-time errors happen when the code violates language rules. In your case you try to read values into a constant string (`const std::string const&`). This is clearly not supposed to work. You rather want to use

```
std::string read_text()
{
    std::string prompt;
    std::cout << "Enter your text: ";
    std::getline(std::cin, prompt);
    return prompt;
}
```

Given that input has a fair chance to fail, that's probably not a really good idea as it seems this interface unconditionally succeeds.

A *segmentation fault*, on the other hand, is a run-time error. More specifically, you get a segmentation fault when a piece of memory is accessed which isn't mapped at the accessed location with appropriate access rights. Typically, there is no memory at all mapped at the accessed location. For example, if you try to dereference a null-pointer and write to it you typically get a segmentation fault. Since the behavior of dereference a null-pointer is formally undefined, there is actually no guarantee that anything specific happens.

The code without the `const` fails to return a value, i.e., there is another form undefined behavior: not returning a value from a non-`void` function is undefined behavior. The compiler probably injected code which tries to build a `std::string` from the content of some register or memory location and that doesn't seem to contain a valid pointer.